# Android Studio fading splash into main

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation, fadein, splash-screen

I currently am working on an android app. Just started and I was able to implement my splash screen. However, I don't like the transition between that and the main activity. I want the splash screen to fade out and main to fade in. Looks like they blend together since I have the same background image for both. Did some research but havent been able to find the right answers.
Below, I have posted my code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class Splash_screen extends Activity {

private Thread mSplashThread;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
    final Splash_screen sPlashScreen = this;

    mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(3000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
            }
            finish();

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    mSplashThread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
{
    if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        synchronized(mSplashThread){
            mSplashThread.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

MainActivity class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Feel free to delete any classes or files not needed for this task.
Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use two .xml files to fade in a new Activity and fade out the current Activity.

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
       android:duration="500" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:fillAfter="true"
       android:duration="500" />
```

Use it in code like that: (Inside your Activity)

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

The above code will fade out the currently active Activity and fade in the newly started Activity.

Comment: which folder would I be creating the 2 .xml files in? @Y.S

Comment: you need to create folder with name as "anim" in your resource folder and create those 2 .xml file in that "anim" folder

Comment: bango. right on thank you @Y.S works like a charm. Such a site for sore eyes.

Comment: I get fade in on splash start very often. Is that still good practice to do that?