# How to make an activity blur then disappear with new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, splash-screen, blur

I have a slpash screen which has one image I want to make the image or activity blur before the next activity gets called.

I tried to use fade_in fade_out anim but its not working.

Tried code given in this accepted answer : [Android Studio fading splash into main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961478/android-studio-fading-splash-into-main)

splashScreen

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private Thread mSplashThread;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;

        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        wait(3000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){
                }

                finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fade_in :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="500" />
```

Fade_out :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="500" />
```

What Can I do for blur animation? I want the slpash activity to look blur before the another activity starts.

Please help.Thank you..

Comment: For this you need to capture the screen and then create the bitmap, now blur the bitmap using scale bitmap, then add that in view So it will show like blur background, and on redirecting to another activity just remove or hide that view from the activity.

Answer (score 0):

If overridePendingTransition doesn't work as you want for fade_in and fade_out.
You can make a workaround. before navigating, make a animation for your app container to Blur, using a animation library like: https://github.com/2359media/EasyAndroidAnimations or https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
And an animation to fade in the content of the next activty,
and use activity.overridePendingTransition(NO_ANIMATION, NO_ANIMATION);

Note: this is not something I tried, but it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can add one overlay in splash_layout as shown below to have the dim effect. and make it visible before starting the new activity.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A0000000"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Hope this helps.